# OrientDB: How to update column using select query

Tags: sql, orientdb

I need to update a column in table using following:

```
update Table1 set name = (select productName from Table2 where
@rid=$parent.$current.productid)
```

Query works fine but instead of name query stores value in "[productname]" format.

I have read orientdb documentation, I guess select query returns result in collection format. so I have already tried following functions

- get(1)
- first()
- [0] etc (my desperate attempt :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried searching but did not get any clean ans, but i making following change worked for me & got the job done :)

```
update Table1 set name=(select productname from Table2 where
@rid=$parent.$current.productid), 
name= name.replace("\[","").replace("\]","")
```

Hope this saves time for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You observe this behavior since the sub query (the select query) always returns a collection. The LET block would help you here. Following is how  you use the LET block in your query;

`update Table1 set name = $name[0].productname
LET $name = (select productname from Table2 where @rid=$parent.$current.productId)`

The LET block is useful for sub queries, projections and holding results that will be used multiple times.

You can find more information [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Query.html#projections).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like LET is not supported for UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your answer (@Omega Silva) does not work as it is.

[This is the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk9K0.png)

I have the same problem here and I haven't found an elegant solution.

I want to copy the @rid of Table2 into a field "r1" of Table1 where Table2.f1=Table1.f2 (f1 & f2 just two other fields).

The only solution I came up with is this:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET r1=(SELECT @rid FROM Table2 
WHERE Table2.f1=$parent.$current.f2)
```

And this returns a string with the entire field/value list.
Then I trim it as follows:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET r1=r1.substring(6,12)
```

(to keep just the @rid part)

But it seems to me that there has to be a better/more elegant solution, with a single query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
update Table1 set name=(select productname from Table2 where
@rid=$parent.$current.productid), 
name= name.replace("[","").replace("]","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that method (hierahical linking)

```
UPDATE test1 SET ttt=(SELECT FROM test1 WHERE id=$parent.$current.parentId),
parent=ttt[0].@rid,ttt=null
```

It is works on orientdb 2.19