# OrientDB SQL - Update with subquery

Tags: sql, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I want to copy the @rid of Table2 into a field "r1" of Table1, where Table2.f1=Table1.f2 (f1 & f2 just two other fields).

The only solution I came up with is this:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET r1=(SELECT @rid FROM Table2 
WHERE Table2.f1=$parent.$current.f2)
```

But it returns a string with the entire field/value list.
So I have to trim it as follows:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET r1=r1.substring(6,12)
```

(to keep just the @rid part)

But it seems to me that there has to be a better/more elegant solution, with a single query.

Is there a way to extract only the @rid from the above field list?

I also tried [Omega Silva's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30746118/6339712), which does not seem to work.
[This is the error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk9K0.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly but I tried with this little example

[image]

and with

```
UPDATE Table1 SET r1=(SELECT @rid FROM Table2 WHERE f1=$parent.$current.f2)
```

I got

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Apparently you did exactly what I did. But the result is not the same.
I get a field list like this (my example is with video detections I get from a MongoDB):
     
[Video#28:16{Mongo_ID:5714c50f142d7d2cf7c100fb,EG_ID:Video_5714c50f142dc100fb,W:576.0,H:704.0,Frames:45061,Label:Video,VideoID:d8637219a389a77bbb65194a} v2]       


The result I get seems to agree with what Omega Silva wrote, that "the sub query (the select query) always returns a collection".
Still confused, cause I already tried this. 
Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yes, the sub query (the select query) always returns a collection.