# Updating value in OrientDB set an array like value

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I tried to run the following command:

```
UPDATE EN190 
set Sys_DisplayTitle = (SELECT EP190_1 FROM EN190 WHERE Sys_ID = 4705)
WHERE Sys_ID = 4706
```

The value of (SELECT EP190_1 FROM EN190 WHERE Sys_ID = 4705) is a string:

> SomeValue

and that what I expected to be in (SELECT EP190_1 FROM EN190 WHERE Sys_ID = 4706)
but the value in this field is now the following string:

> [SomeValue]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not a really "clean" solution, but it works.

```
UPDATE EN190 set Sys_DisplayTitle = (SELECT EP190_1 FROM EN190 WHERE Sys_ID = 4705),
Sys_DisplayTitle= Sys_DisplayTitle.replace("[","").replace("]","")
WHERE Sys_ID = 4706
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30724286/5778523)

Answer (score 0):

The following query `SELECT EP190_1 FROM EN190 WHERE Sys_ID = 4705`
return a list not a string

Comment: Yes I figured this out, the question is how can I return a single value? I tried using First and asString but it doesn't work